# Android "Zombie" BLE Advertising Task

Tags: android, process, bluetooth-lowenergy, ads

In my App, i have a `Service` including a `Thread` that ciclycally starts and stops BLE Advertising:

```
public class BeaconSearchService extends Service {

     private void startAdvertisingThread() {
         (advertisingThread = new Thread("Advertising Thread") {
             @Override
             public void run() {
                //Ensure that advertising is off
                try {
                   BeaconSearchService.this.bluetoothLeAdvertiser.stopAdvertising(BeaconSearchService.this.advertiseCallback);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                }
                while(!isInterrputed()) {
                   AdvertiseSettings advertiseSettings = new AdvertiseSettings.Builder()
                      .setAdvertiseMode(AdvertiseSettings.ADVERTISE_MODE_LOW_LATENCY)
                      .setTxPowerLevel(AdvertiseSettings.ADVERTISE_TX_POWER_MEDIUM)
                      .setConnectable(true)
                      .build();
                   BeaconSearchService.this.advertiseData.getServiceUuids().clear();
                   BeaconSearchService.this.advertiseData.getServiceUuids().add(BeaconSearchService.this.getUuid());
                   long uptime = 5000;
                   long downTime = 7000;
                   //START ADVERTISING
                   try {
                       BeaconSearchService.this.bluetoothLeAdvertiser.startAdvertising(advertiseSettings, BeaconSearchService.this.advertiseData, BeaconSearchService.this.advertiseCallback);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        Log.e(LOG_TAG, e.getMessage(), e);
                    }
                    //SLEEP FOR 5 SEC
                    try {
                        sleep(upTime);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        interrupt();
                        break;
                    }
                    //AFTER WAKE FROM SLEEP, STOP ADVERTISING
                    try {
                       BeaconSearchService.this.bluetoothLeAdvertiser.stopAdvertising(BeaconSearchService.this.advertiseCallback);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        Log.e(LOG_TAG, e.getMessage(), e);
                    }
                    //SLEEP FOR 7 SEC
                    try {
                        sleep(downTime);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        interrupt();
                        break;
                    }
                    //RESTART THE CIRCLE IF NOT INTERRUPTED
             }
             //Ensure stop advertising while exiting
             try {
               BeaconSearchService.this.bluetoothLeAdvertiser.stopAdvertising(BeaconSearchService.this.advertiseCallback);
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
         }).start();
     }

     @Override
     public void onDestroy() {
         try {
            advertisingThread.interrupt();
         } catch(Exception e) {
         }
     }
}
```

The problem is that when the Advertising is ON and `Service` and `Thread` are closed WITHOUT calling the `onDestroy()` method (e.g. App Crash, App process killed by the Local Android ROM Custom Behavior or while developing with Android Studio, App restart after new version download from Playstore etc), the Android system keeps the BLE Advertising ON. So when I reopen the App and sniff the BLE Packets I see TWO or More Advertising "sessions" of my App. The problem is solved when I reboot the phone and "orphan" Advertisig sessions disappear.

Is there any way to kill all the "zombie" Advertising sessions without forcing the user to reboot his phone?

Comment: you could use the onTrimMemory() callback to get when system memory is less and your service can be killed

Comment: There is no any memory problem, the problem is that sometimes I haven't the chance to manually Stop Advertising and it survives to the process kill.

Comment: well it happens only in 2 scenario as you mentioned, when app crashes or system kills it, when system kills it , it will call the onTrimMemory before that , when your app crash you could a use defaultexceptionhandler to kill the zombie process also

Comment: Which android version and device do you have? Seems like a bug...

Comment: I use a series of Samsung devices with Android 5.01/6: S5, S7 Edge, Tab...
@ColdFire Is onTrimMemory called the 100% of the times in the 100% of the Android OS Customizations? I had, for example, a problem with Huawei P8 Operative System Customization that has a built-in procedure that automatically closes in a hard way the process of apps in background or when the phone goes in standby.

Comment: yes AFAIK, but IMO this is most probably a bug in android OS, there is little point in keeping zombie process alive , maybe you should file a bug report with AOSP android

Comment: Is it possible that Google left a so-ugly bug? Does anyone have the some problem that confirms it?

Comment: What does advertisingThread.interrupt() do ?

Comment: It is the default java.lang.Thread::interrupt method: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#interrupt()